# How to write a script could restart the job when exceeding a limit time in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm writing a script could do the same job 100 times and each in a different directory (named run1 to run100). However, the job will stuck for a long time sometimes and I have to delete the directory containing that run and restart it.
Is it possible to write a script that could 1. stop and delete the directory (e.g., run13) if that run exceeds 6 hours and 2. restart that run again?
Here is my original shell script

```
PREFIX=earlymigration
for i in {1..100}
 do
   mkdir run$i
   cp ${PREFIX}.tpl ${PREFIX}.est ${PREFIX}_jointMAFpop1_0.obs run$i"/"
   cd run$i
   fsc26 -t ${PREFIX}.tpl -e ${PREFIX}.est -m -0 -C 10 -n 200000 -L 40 -s0 -M -c 10
   cd ..
 done
```

Comment: You can have your script write the PID for each job, the directory being operated on, and the time started (in seconds since epoch) to a run-file (some file you create in, e,g  `/run/user/UID/scriptname`). Have a cron-job (or systemd timer) run a second script that reads the run-file and check if the PID is still running and if so get the difference in time between now and when the job was started). If it exceeds 6 hour, kill the PID and restart the job for that directory and write a new entry in the run-file. If the PID no longer exists, delete the run-file entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So do exactly that. Timeout the command, and if it times out, restart it.

```
while true; do
   timeout $((6 * 60 * 60)) fsc26 ....
   ret=$?
   if ((ret == 124)); then
       rm the_directory_containing_that_run
       continue
   fi
   break
done
```

See `man timeou`.

Comment: thanks for sharing this code, it works well when I put it into the original for loop